# Laravel Backpack use custom build for ckeditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, ckeditor5, laravel-backpack

I am using Laravel 10 + Backpack 6.
Backpack 6 used ckeditor5 under the hood.

I want to use custom  build of ckeditor with some additional plugins.
I did everything is mention in this post - [CKEditor toolbars in Backpack](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/issues/559#issuecomment-1630673757)
and here is my file structure with defenition of field:
[image]

Unfortunately it does not work. In browser i see that server returns 404 for my scripts:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you placed the files in the correct path: `\resources\assets\ckeditor\ckeditor.js`.

**Make sure you only placed there what's inside the build folder.**

```
\translations\
\ckeditor.js
\ckeditor.js.map
```

If that path is correct, please go to basset folder (default is `\public\storage\basset\`) and check if the files are cached there, at `\public\storage\basset\resources\assets\ckeditor\ckeditor.js`.

I'm assuming basset is working properly for you and the admin panel has no issues, so it should be related with this paths

If the files are there, it should work.
If the files aren't there, something is wrong with the placement of the files.

Let me know

Comment: I don't know how.. Did the same on fresh install - works fine.. Question can be closed

Comment: So my mistake was in wrong folder. I didn't know that your backpack manages ckeditor folder and copies it from resources to baseet